# how to call jquery function without having to trigger selector event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, function

How do I call a jquery function by just loading the page? For example, on one page,I have a paragraph and this jquery code here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide(1000);
  });
});
```

How do I make the paragraph slowly fade away using jquery right after the page loads WITHOUT having any user input like clicking the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just call hide like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a small warning..
`$('p')` will select all the paragraphs in the page..
use the selector more clearly..

to achieve the requirement, you can add this line as said above..

```
$("button").click();
```

or

```
$("button").trigger('click');
```

A much better way of wiring this is..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide(1000);
  }).trigger('click');

});
```

this will improve the performance by reducing the no.of search cycles.. :)

cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide(1000);
  });

  $("button").click();

});
```

Just add that line.

Comment: The other answers are also ok, but if you do it that way, the button never will have that event, if you click on it.

Comment: -1: no need to invoke click on the button. see the other answers

Comment: but @user701510 in his question not asked to leave this function on his button

Answer (score 1):

just like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide(1000);
});
```

Comment: You don't know if he wants to have that event on the button. The question is not clear enough about it.

Comment: "[...] WITHOUT having any user input like clicking the button?" sounds like he does not want to have any user interaction.

Comment: I don't agree with that. He doesn't sais that he doesn't want the event on the button. I understand it's just at the moment of loading the page. Why to do it with the button then?